# Unusual regexp with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to match a text starting with '• To start here' (bullet followed by a space and "To start here").
Does someone know how to do it ?

I keep searching and if I find the solution I'll post it.

edit (my attempt) :

```
var result = assertion.search(<li>(.To start here)</li>)
```

thanks,

Bruno

Comment: Did you try `• To start here.*`? Unicode characters are just characters ;-) Note that if you look inside some HTML you won't find that *if* the bullet is actually a character rendered by a `<li>` (because in that case it's not part of the text).

Comment: Thanks for answering but it doesn't work. Could you please write it so I could check if I wrote it correctly ?

Comment: you should edit to show what you tried instead so others can correct any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking for the bullets in a unordered list in html, right? something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>To start Here</li>
<li>Another bullet</li>
</ul>
```

The regex for that would be:

```
<li>(.*?)</li>
```

The group '(.*?)' will catch the phrase you're looking for.

EDIT:
Then what you must do to catch the phrases is:

```
   var regx = new RegExp('<li>(.*?)</li>');
   var result = regx.exec('<li>Hi there!</li>');
   alert (result[1]);
```

This will alert 'Hi there!' on the browser.

Whenever you're in doubt, try the awesome [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/).

cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it would be something like : var result = assertion.search(<li>(.*?)</li>) ?

Comment: Just updated the javascript code, but I'm wondering what's the exact html you're putting your code to work against. can you show us that?

Comment: oh, and if you're willing to itereate over the results check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex